# Batteries Burning when circuit turned off

Tags: batteries, circuit-design

I have very little electrical engineering background, only a little from college physics.

I'm making a battery powered light for some kid that plays basketball so he can see his basket better at night. It works until I turn it off, then after about 30 seconds it begins to fizzle and heat up. I can then smell the smell of burning plastic coming from the battery housing.

Each LED light in the diagram is 3V.

What am I doing wrong? It works fine when powered on, it doesn't overheat then.

Thanks! 
[image: Circuit sketch]

Comment: Your switch is wired incorrectly.  You're turning it off by shorting the battery which could certainly cause a fire or be dangerous.  The switch needs to be in series with the lights.

Comment: The switch is in parallel with the load (i.e. the lights), so you are shorting battery terminals together.  The switch should be in series with the load.

Comment: You also need current-limiting resistors in series with each LED or each group of series-connected LEDs, as shown in the second circuit in @transistor's answer.

Comment: +1 for actually providing a diagram which makes your question answerable. With a little persistence, you'll get better at "designs that work."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWhMGs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Correct, the way the switch is connected, you are shorting the battery to turn the lights off. Disconnect the switch from the wires. Choose either the black wire or the red wire. Cut it. Connect the switch between those wires.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have wired the switch as you have shown then the battery permanently powers the LEDs. What the switch does is to short circuit the battery. It may appear that the LEDs go out, but all that's happening is that the battery is short circuit. The switch should be in series with the +ve lead. The -ve lead should not go to the switch.